# how to use Web3j library for android

Tags: web3js, web3j

hi guys i am confuse about the web3j library for android i search about this but i did not get any materiel about this (https://github.com/web3j/web3j). this is lib for using ether node on java and for android i don't know how to use this. following things i already done .
1 -> Ethereum Node syncing (full node)
2 -> make web interface using Web3.js lib.
3 -> creating address and managing account on ether using cli with Web3.js

now i want to use this thing on android also please help me how i can use this web3j lib on android how to configure .

Comment: You can refer to this below link. It will provide you the example related to web3j API.
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?ClassName=web3j&action=search&submit=Search

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a medium article just on this topic (Getting started with web3j on Android), I hope it helps: https://medium.com/@nschapeler/an-introduction-to-ethereum-development-on-android-using-web3j-and-infura-763940719997

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my project on Github, I used Kotlin to build it
https://github.com/wise4rmgod/Web3Js-Android

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).